# Forms and Reports 10g to 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I will need to migrate Forms an Reports from 10g to 11g. I need to know did anyone had done something similar and what problems I may discover in the process? Maybe some of you have useful links or information to share? Most of documentation about migrating 6i to 11g. So I having hard time discovering what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few differences, it depends on what you use. If you use some deprecated stuff from 10g it can be deleted now. But I have migrated over 4000 forms and didn't found much strange things. However you might have some strange behavior if you also go from oracle DB 10 to oracle DB 11. I would say at this moment just migrate run all your forms and change some things that don't work, it won't be too much you have to change.

Comment: Thanks for advise, you made me worry less. I have over 1500 forms and even more reports. today I will try to migrate 10 or 20 by hands and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I faced these problems when migrating Oracle 10g to 11g, main problems is from Oracle 6i, becouse it was still used in migration and all forms have to work in 6i, 10g and 11g:

1. RUN_PRODUCT was eliminated from Oracle 11g. This procedure was in background in Oracle 10g.
2. CHART type was eliminated in Oracle 11g. This field type was in background in Oracle 10g.
3. Some of 10g PLL's freezes Forms Builder 11g. I readed that in 11.1.0.7 is a bug fix for this problem, but I use 11.1.2 and still get same problem, so I created work-around for this problem.